# Format a FTQuery to find a field containing a role

Tags: full-text-search, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I need to find all the documents in a database that the field wfsCurrApp contains a given role. in the search bar I entered  field WFSCurrApp contains [Finance] but I get the error that the query is not understandable. If I change it to  field WFSCurrApp contains "[Finance]" the query runs but returns nothing. 
What I'm ultimately trying to get done is something like this because the user may possess several roles in the target database I believe the issue is the [] as that is used to delimit dates, but ????:

```
var uRoles = thisDB.queryAccessRoles( context.getUser().getDistinguishedName());
        var userRoles:String = "";
        var it:java.util.Iterator = uRoles.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                var thisRole = it.next()
                if (userRoles == "") {
                    userRoles = thisRole
                }else{
                    userRoles = userRoles + " OR " + thisRole;
                }
            }
tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD WFSCurrApp CONTAINS (\"" + userRoles + "\"))";
```

**Edited:**
tmpArray  has this in it

(FIELD WFSCurrApp CONTAINS ("[Finance]")) when the user has a single role and

(FIELD WFSCurrApp CONTAINS ("[Finance]" OR "[WFSAdmin]")) if the user has multiple roles. Neither of these return any documents that I know have the role [Finance] in the Current Approvers field WFSCurrApp.

The query has a number of other tags so tmpArray is split and each element is seperated with an "OR". This is the final query

(FIELD WFSCurrApp CONTAINS "Barney Rubble/Workflo Systems") OR (FIELD WFSCurrApp CONTAINS ("[Finance]"))

the query returns the documents where WFSCurrApp contains Barney but not the ones where Barney's role is [Finance] and there are some that Barney is not in the current approvers but he possess the role [Finance] and that role is in the Current Approvers.

The query returns without error and returns the documents where Barney is listed in the Current Approvers so there are no errors raised, just does not find the matching role.

Comment: Have you checked with a console log  whats inside you search query when you quit the while loop?

Comment: I have no problems with square brackets inside quotes. Tested with my mail and have not found any problem with query you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Started Working correctly so guess it might have been an index update issue